# How to Make a scrollable table without the column shrinking?

Tags: php, html, css, menu, html-table

I need to make a scrollable menu, currently, I'm using table to create the button and got it working as below.

[image]

I want the button to be as above, and when I add another button I want it to be hidden and I can use the right button to show the button on the right but hide one button on the left, but when I add a button instead of scrollable, it shrink my button and only stop shrinking after I add about another 10 button and only this time the left and right button to be working.

[image]

What I'm looking for is that only 9 button as the first picture button to be shown and the rest of the button that I'll be adding will need to be scroll using the right button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #header {
            border-style:solid;
            border-color:skyblue;
            height:105px;
        }

        #content {
            border-style:solid;
            border-color:skyblue;
            min-height:300px;
            margin-top : 3px;
            margin-bottom : 3px;
        }

        #footer {
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: skyblue;
        }

        #tab {
            display:block;
            vertical-align:top;
            margin-top:1%;
            overflow:auto;
        }

        .pad {
            height:70px;
            width:82px;
            padding:15px 15px 3px 15px;
            text-align:center;
            font-weight:bold;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
            border:solid 1px;
            border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        }

        .pad:hover {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
        }

        .button_gmb {
            height:40px;
            width:48px;
            margin-top:-10px;
        }

        .button_gmb:hover {
            height:50px;
            width:58px;
        }

        .next {
            background-image:url('pictures/right.png');
            position:absolute;
            top:8%;
            left:95%;
        }

       .previous {
            position:absolute;
            top:8%;
            left:17%;
        }
   </style>
    </head>
    <body>
           <script>
     function scrollWinLeft() {
         document.getElementById("a").scrollLeft += -60;
      }

         function scrollWinRight() {
      document.getElementById("a").scrollLeft += 103;
}
  </script>
       <div id ="header">
                <img ID ="Image1" src="pictures/logo_kolej.png" style = "margin-top:27px;margin-left:5px;width:180px"/>
                <button class="previous" onclick="scrollWinLeft()"/>Left </button>
                 <div id = "a" style="position:absolute;top: 3%;left:18%; width:80%;height:50%">
                  <table border="0" id="tab" style="margin-top:-2px;margin-left:30px; overflow-y:scroll;"  >
                    <tr>
                         <td class="pad"><a href="home.php?page=home"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/Home.png" /><br />Home</a></td>
                          <td class="pad"><a href="home.php?page=schedule"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/Efficient-Diary-logo.png"/><br />Schedule</a></td>
                          <td class="pad"><a href="home.php?page=finance"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/3-people-logo.png"><br />Finance</a></td>
                         <td class="pad"><a href="home.php?page=chat.php"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/Event.png"/><br />Chat</a></td>
                          <td class="pad"><a href="home.php?page=Gallery.php"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/Apps-Gallery-icon.png"/><br />Gallery</a></td>
                         <td class="pad"><a href="home.php?page=index.php"><img class="button_gmb" style="margin-right:18px;" src="pictures/logout.png"/><br />Logout</a></td>
                          <td class="pad"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/time.png"/><br /></td>
                          <td class="pad"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/time.png"/><br /></td>
                         <td class="pad"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/time.png"/><br /></td>
                         <td class="pad"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/time.png"/><br /></td>
                       <td class="pad"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/time.png"/><br /></td>
                        <td class="pad"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/time.png"/><br /></td>
                         <td class="pad"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/time.png"/><br /></td>
                         <td class="pad"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/time.png"/><br /></td>
                        <td class="pad"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/time.png"/><br /></td>
                        <td class="pad"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/time.png"/><br /></td>
                       <td class="pad"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/time.png"/><br /></td>
                        <td class="pad"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/time.png"/><br /></td>
                          <td class="pad"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/time.png"/><br /></td>
                          <td class="pad"><img class="button_gmb" src="pictures/time.png"/><br /></td>

                 </tr>
             </table>
            </div>
            <button class="next" onclick="scrollWinRight()">Right</button>
        </div>

   <div id ="content">
       <div style="margin-left:50px;margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:30px;margin-right:50px;">
             <?php
             if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
                $page_name = $_GET['page'];
               include("pages/".$page_name.".php");
             }
           ?>
       </div>
   </div>

  <div id ="footer">
       <p style ="text-align:center;margin-top:3px;">2016 © Copyright Family Management System | All Rights Reserved </p>
  </div>
```

This is my first project and I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the bootstrap table class ".table-responsive" and use the following css code-

```
.table-responsive {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .table-responsive > .table {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .table-responsive > .table > thead > tr > th,
    .table-responsive > .table > tbody > tr > th,
    .table-responsive > .table > tfoot > tr > th,
    .table-responsive > .table > thead > tr > td,
    .table-responsive > .table > tbody > tr > td,
    .table-responsive > .table > tfoot > tr > td {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered {
        border: 0;
    }
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > th:first-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th:first-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th:first-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > td:first-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td:first-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td:first-child {
        border-left: 0;
    }
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > th:last-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th:last-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th:last-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > td:last-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td:last-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td:last-child {
        border-right: 0;
    }
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr:last-child > th,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr:last-child > th,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr:last-child > td,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr:last-child > td {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thanks alot for the code, haven't test it out yet, I will test it out and tell you the result. Thanks again sir..